# Linq Selector with dynamic property name

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda, selector

I have an `IQueryable<TEntity>` where `TEntity` is another class `BaseEntity<TKey, TUId>`.

Because `BaseEntity<TKey, TUid>` have two generic parameters, I must know `TKey` and `TUId` types in advance if I want to select a column from the `IQueryable`.

But I also know that `BaseEntity<TKey, TUId>` will always have a numeric property named `UId`, and that is what I need to get.

What I´m trying to achieve is something like the following code, where I can define a selector variable with the property I want the query to select, but dynamically. Like setting this name in a string variable.

```
var selector = nameof(BaseEntity<,>.UId);
IQueryable<TEntity> query = GetQueryByPrimaryKey();
var entityUId = Convert.ToInt64(query.Select(selector).Single());
```

Having a constraint in the `TEntity` to accept only `BaseEntity<TKey, TUId>` is not an option, because I don´t have the Type of every parameter, and I would need to define every possibility.

Is there any way to create a dynamic lambda selector to indicate the string name of the property I want to get?

The main objetive is to perform a single query to the database using the primary key and select only one field (the mapped UId column) to improve performance.

I have read some solutions and some pointed out Dynamic Query, but I prefer a native solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to create a dynamic expression and call `Select` on it:

```
private Expression<Func<BaseEntity<TKey, TUId>, long>> CreateUIdExpression<TKey,
 TUId>()
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BaseEntity<TKey, TUId>));
    var memberExpression = Expression.Property(param, "UId");
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<BaseEntity<TKey, TUId>, long>>(memberExpression, param);

    return expr;
}
```

Usage:

```
var newQuery = query.Select(CreateUIdExpression<TKey, TUId>());
```

BTW, I've assumed that UId is a long.

Comment: Works great, I actually changed BaseEntity<TKey, TUId> for T to be reusable. The only issue I´m having is that the type is not always long, it can be long, int, short, byte. I´ll try to fix that. Thank you!